# Display selected attributes on category page

Tags: php, undefined, opencart

I am using `OpenCart v1.5.4`. I want to display product attribute also on the category page. Have searched but cannot find a module or solution for this.

I am trying to add a certain attribute (one attribute group from 3, not all attributes) to category page and I am getting this error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: attribute_groups in /catalog/view/theme/bigshop/template/product/category.tpl on line 79

Can anyone help?

This is the code I used on my product page and it works great but not on category page.

```
<?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
      <?php if ($attribute_group['name'] == 'Product Info') { ?>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
          <span><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></span> <?php echo html_entity_decode($attribute['text']); ?><br />
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- End Additional Info -->
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing PHP on every line? Yikes!

Comment: I don't know any other way . please let me know  if you know any other way i am new to this and learning. Thanks.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Because it's an HTML template file. And because this is a good practice for templates. And even if it wouldn't it's OpenCart's convention to do so.

Comment: You need to take a look at `catalog/controller/product/product.php` and check how the `$this->data['attribute_groups']` are instantiated. Then you need to copy over this part of code to your `catalog/controller/product/category.php` controller.

Comment: i tried that but group of attributes show up. i just want an attribute to show under the name . the structure of category and product page seems different.